# Is a bounty still auto-awarded if you downvote the answer?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

I asked a question. I put up a bounty after a period with no answers, and there was only one answer. Nobody else answered, and one person voted this answer up (only one, no downvotes). I voted that answer down, because it was wrong and I did not want it to get my bounty.

When the time came for the bounty to be auto-awarded, it just... disappeared. The bounty was removed from the question and no answer was accepted. I don't know if this was because I downvoted the only answer, or there was no upvoted answer, or something else. Can somebody please explain how this works?

(If you are wondering what question: [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent). The other answers were added much afterward the bounty ended.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The highest upvoted answer gets half of the bounty. If you accept an answer, it gets full bounty. If no answers have more than two upvotes, no bounty will be awarded.

[Bounty FAQ item.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483019/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow/483070#483070)

Also this snippet from the [Blog.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/)

> You do not accept an answer. Any answer that was a) provided after the bounty period started and b) **has 2 or more upvotes** is automatically accepted after 7 days. The bounty is subtracted from your reputation. The answerer is awarded half the bounty amount (unless it’s your own answer, see #3 below).

But if you downvote an answer that has many upvotes, and in the end that answer is at the top (with two or more upvotes, and you didn't accept another one) that answer will get the bounty.