# Tentatively award bounty : better control of auto-award

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I currently have a bounty on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4865616/412770); and an answer in mind that I would like to award it  to. However, there's still a few days left on the bounty and  I don't want to jump the gun and award it now, in case a better and more deserving answer shows up before time.

On the other hand, if I leave it too late and am otherwise occupied (read: sleeping) when the bounty expires, the system may not award it to anyone / award it to some other answer I feel is less deserving.

What I would like to do is set up a standing, revocable instruction to award the bounty at expiry to an answer of my choice. If a better answer shows up that I happen to review, I should be able to change my mind (switch standing instruction / manually award it); otherwise the system should carry out the standing instruction on expiry.

I'm sure other askers have faced a similar situation but have had to make a sub-optimal decision /  the auto-award rules have not worked as they would have liked.

Thoughts?

(Note: This is different from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6995/151188), which is more about *informing* the user about how the system would work if things ran their course.)

Comment: Asking questions comes with some responsibility!

Comment: @Arjan: I don't think any of the following show *irresponsibility* : a) the desire to award someone with something they deserve b) not wanting to exclude future deserving potential awardees because I made a rash decision c) having the 'cheek' to be busy when some arbitrary timer runs out.

Comment: Somehow folks rarely miss a doctor's appointment ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: Asking questions comes with responsibility, but answering questions comes with... bacon?

Comment: Alternative proposals: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242522/can-a-user-award-half-their-bounty-after-being-awol , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251099/why-cant-i-finish-awarding-bounty-after-grace-period