# Why can't I finish awarding bounty after grace period?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, expired-bounty

I put a bounty on this question

[How to get style attribute value before IE9 strips it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796112/how-to-get-style-attribute-value-before-ie9-strips-it)

And didn't get back to award it fast enough so it auto awarded half.  I want to award the rest though.  I put it up and the answerer deserves it.  Why can't I finish awarding?

Comment: Good question, but probably the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242522/can-a-user-award-half-their-bounty-after-being-awol ?