# Bounty not given when more than one equally upvoted answers

Tags: discussion, bounties

Is this how it is supposed to work?

Two answers to a question, both get a single upvote, no accepted answer.

The result is that no bounty points are distributed or deducted from the user who answered the question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: First line, that's the question. Is this the intended behavior.

Comment: This is called unresolved bounty and has been discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-happens-if-there-are-no-answers-to-a-bounty-question/9932#9932 . And yes, this is by design. For now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Confident:** Bounty is only awarded if there are at least two upvotes for the top answer.

**[Confident](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/#comment-13333):** Oldest answer is awarded the bounty in the case of a tie.

Answer (score 1):

It should also be noted that, in addition to the auto-accepted answer needing to have at least 2 upvotes, it also has to be posted **after the bounty was added** to be eligible for auto-acceptance.