# Why can't I choose a correct answer for this question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Why is it that I can't choose an accepted answer for this question? The "accepted answer" option does not show up.

[Unsafe use of user-supplied GString:s in Groovy/Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671512/unsafe-use-of-user-supplied-gstrings-in-groovy-grails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/671512/list) history you've previously had a bounty on the question and never accepted an answer. This is discussed and explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-happens-if-there-are-no-answers-to-a-bounty-question).

Comment: bawwww 4 seconds

Answer (score 3):

It's a known "bug". It is a result of an unresolved bounty (you did not select a winner, and one was not auto selected since no post had 2 or more votes). You will no longer be able to select an answer on this question.

Comment: +1 I only took long with editing mine to get all the details :)