# Bounty Question Not Answered and Reputation Points Lost

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if there are no answers to a bounty question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-happens-if-there-are-no-answers-to-a-bounty-question)

Is there any reason why rep. points aren't returned from a bounty if no one has answered my question? If you're an admin/moderator who can see that this question had a bounty until an hour ago, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499598/programmatically-adding-two-infragistics-ultrawebgrids-renders-only-one-grid-with

Comment: I had to add the feature-request tag for some reason.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-happens-if-there-are-no-answers-to-a-bounty-question
and also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty

Comment: This is not a duplicate. OP asked WHY. This is not answered in the linked dups.