# Clarification about Bounty

Tags: support, bounties

I know "What is bounty?"

I just want to know

- If I bounty a question with 50 reputation, then is it necessary that after 7 days, I have to accept some answer? If the answer does not satisfy me then what will happen?
- Whether my 50 rep will be deducted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to accept an answer, but you lose your 50 reps anyway. Half of the bounty is given to the answer which has got the most votes with the condition of having minimum of 2 votes. If there is no answer with 2 or more votes, then the question stays permanent.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9902/140794) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1413/140794) questions for more info.