# Badge for Closing Question

Tags: feature-request, badges

I think we should have a badge ( or a set of badges) for the users who close a sufficient number of questions. Closing question is a form of community service and therefore deserves rewards.

**Note: Now don't try to close this question in the name of [illustrating the irony :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/please-do-not-auto-select-answers-on-bounty-questions)!**

Comment: interesting thoguht.. akin to "Civic Duty", you're thinking?

Comment: @warren, yup that's what I have in mind..

Comment: I think the abuse of this could be well balanced with a similar badge for re-opening questions

Comment: @Michael: Good idea!

Comment: It could be called "Junior Janitor" -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance/32515#32515

Comment: I posted a related request on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272898/badge-proposal-deduplicator-nominated-to-close-as-duplicate-with-link-x-15

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This could make sense since closing is now a community process, requiring 5 votes to accomplish.  That means that rather than awarding a badge based on simply voting to close (could encourage voting to close for no good reason), or based on casting the final vote (unfair to others who voted to close, and creates unusual incentives when votes approach 4 or 5), I'd propose that the badge be based on:

**Casting X votes to close on questions which were then subsequently closed.**

As an arbitrary suggestion, I'd say X = 25.

This means that everyone who votes to close would get credit towards their X, but only if the question was actually later closed (signifying that your vote was a "correct" vote).  This does make it a little more attractive for those who wait until the 5th vote, but I don't see that as a major problem, as all voters still get credit.

I'd propose that questions that are re-opened should *not* rescind the associated tally, because a question could be re-opened after editing and be different from the form that was closed.  Indeed, the close process can play a part in encouraging questioners to shape up their questions, and so the votes to close should still be recognized as a valuable part of that process even if it gets re-opened later.

The only problem I can see is that this kind of badge might be difficult to calculate and implement for the dev team, as it relies on keeping a tally on information which is transient in the system.  It may not be technically feasible without major work.

Comment: are we going to get any more updates on this?

Comment: I second the want for more updates...

Answer (score 10):

To be honest, I'm not sure sure is such a good idea if the badge is awarded for closing a large number of questions as it might encourage some users to vote to close questions that may not need to be closed just to get the badge.

That said though, I think it would also be in keeping with the trend in some of the other badges to award one for the *first* question that you vote to close that is also closed as that would encourage users who just got their "Vote to Close" permissions to try them out which is how some of the other badges are designed.

Comment: (Repsonsibly) voting to close questions is something that all users with sufficient reputation should be doing, just like responsibly editing posts. Just because there is a badge for editing questions doesn't mean that *all* posts should be edited, so likewise having a badge for closing questions doesn't mean that *all* posts should be closed. It's just another Junior Janitor task that we should all be undertaking :)

Answer (score 4):

I favor a 3 tier badge system with bronze, silver, and gold badges. It is not enough to close enough questions to get one badge, people should *continually* close questions that are duplicated content or require work from the asker to be up to standard.

All the rewards right now are stacked towards asking questions and answering them. We need additional gamification to encourage users to also keep this site clean. Closing questions is one of those mechanisms. Too few people do it.

Comment: (I have not observed any movement on this front, nor have I found anything related with a *status-declined* tag. Answer posted as serious proposal to renew this effort.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real issue would be to determine how to issue - back in the olden days, ***any*** user with sufficiently-high rep could close. Now it takes a group effort.

And what about if the question is reopened? Does the 'Close' badge go away?

Comment: Normal procedure would be the badge doesn't go away but the next time you earned the badge your total wouldn't go up. Having said that my Beta badge of SF disappeared and the next time I earned a badge the totals were recalculated - but I think that was a special case.