# Badge for voting to close

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)
>   [Badge for Closing Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25053/badge-for-closing-question)

Since voting to close is behavior that should be encouraged, why are there no badges for it?

I was thinking that there should be badges for it similar to the way there are badges for voting in general (bronze for first one, some large number for silver, and much larger number for gold) but I am curious to see what others think.

Thoughts?

Comment: Two words that sour every proposal to reward closing questions: **Pile-on voting**.

Comment: Had a guy today who was going through all questions with -10 or more votes from 2+ years ago, flagging them as "not constructive".  No, we don't need this, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Voting to close is behavior that should be encouraged.

no...

> Voting to close **when appropriate** is behavior that should be encouraged.

closer...

> Not asking questions which are not appropriate for the site is behavior that should be encouraged.  Additionally, editing and improving questions which *are* appropriate for the site so as to make them answerable and beneficial to the community is behavior that should be encouraged.

There we go.  And we *do* have badges for edits.

Comment: I agree entirely. Voting to close is a *necessary evil* that we have available, and unfortunately need to use all-too-often. But I wouldn't say it's something we want to actually encourage.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Indeed, it's attacking the symptom rather than the cause.  (Incidentally, this up-vote put me over 3,000, which gives me the ability to vote to close.  My first vote to close was on this question about voting to close.  That's a lot of meta... on Meta.)

Comment: Speaking of 'voting to close', I believe you've just gained that ability here, thanks to my vote! hehe... Now, don't go getting crazy on us!!

Comment: @AndrewBarber: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/825478#825478