# How do close votes count towards the reviewer badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, vote-to-close, review

Relative to the [New Community Review badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) question, I'm wondering about the process for tracking close votes towards the reviewer & steward badges.  (One side issue here, do we really want to incentivize closing questions? It seems like that will lead to a less hospitable site...)  When you vote to close (or disagree, I suppose) with a question listed in the Close Votes section of the new review, you get another tick mark in your tally, but this only counts for questions that are listed in that section.  That is, it only counts if you're not the first person to vote to close.  When you vote to close on a new question, and no one else has seen it yet, you don't get credit.  If you do that within the First Posts section, you would get credit towards that, but not for the Close Votes portion.  I guess the argument would be that maybe people would go willy-nilly in hopes of getting a badge (again, do we want to incentivize that?), but if others subsequently also vote to close, that suggests there may have been some merit to the vote.

On a slightly different topic, I can understand how it is [difficult to port your progress towards the old badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges#comment424745_147925) to the new ones, but it shouldn't be difficult to do with the close votes, because that number is listed right there on the old page.  It should be ported, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reviewing First Posts and you vote to close the question, then yes, your tally counts towards your First Posts tally, as it should. You didn't review the question from the Close Votes task. Just like if you vote to close completely outside the review panel, it doesn't count towards *any* of the tasks, because you didn't complete the action from within the review panel.

As for making it less hospitable, I don't see how that would happen. Your count still increases for voting *not* to close the question, so voting to close and not close are both encouraged equally. In fact, voting to close requires **more** effort than voting not to close. If anything, I'd expect fewer questions to be closed than were previously. Voting to close requires clicking a button *plus* selecting an appropriate option from the list (and potentially a second option) *plus* clicking another button, while voting not to close requires the click of a single button.

Overall, the badges are for *using* each individual review task. Anything other than "Not Sure" should contribute to your tally for taking action.

Comment: +1, thanks for your prompt response, @animuson. I appreciate your argument re incentivizing & I find it reassuring. FWIW, I'm sorry to hear that the badges are really for using the review system (although I guess I understand it). I'm happy to help maintain the site (CV primarily) & have put in a lot of time doing so, but I really dislike the new system--I find it makes reviewing more of a hassle than the old system, or just commenting & editing etc from the standard pages accessed from the main site's front page.

Answer (score 4):

Just to make this explicit: **there is no badge for voting to close**.

There's a badge for *reviewing questions* that might be closed. [As animuson notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148062/question-about-how-close-votes-are-counted-towards-reviewer-badge/148064#148064) though, you don't have to vote to close them to get credit toward the badge.

Incidentally, this is what makes backfilling reviews from the old system somewhere between "hard" and "impossible" - *all* we have are the votes. If you *edited* 200 questions from the old close tab (surely a heroic effort), that wasn't tracked separately. And if you voted to close from the First Questions tab, that went toward your "Voted to Close" tally as well.

#### Related: [Badge for Closing Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25053/badge-for-closing-question)