# Close votes (etc) outside of review count as review tasks

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close

Can closing questions when not in [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) (so just browsing a question and clicking <kbd>close</kbd>) be counted as a review task?

I mostly don't use the review queue to cast close votes (there I don't feel I make a big difference), but I often do when browsing questions, so some progress towards [the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2279/steward) would be cool.

I'm not sure what currently happens regarding this, but the same can be said for <kbd>reopen</kbd> and <kbd>edit (1)</kbd> (suggested edits) (and I'm guessing <kbd>delete</kbd>).

I'll note that to technically classify as a review task, one vote would already need to have been cast on the question (N/A to suggested edits) (whether or not to apply this is arguable).

Comment: Voting to close outside of review is *not* a review task and shouldn't be treated as one.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly: to me this sounds like a blatant ploy to get the `/review`-related badges.

The short answer is **no** and I'm marking this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

The long answer is a bit more wordy.

Voting to close *outside of the review queue* is in no way a review task -- ***it's a basic function of being a responsible community member***. If you see crummy questions in the course of browsing a site, it is *your responsibility* as a productive member of this community to downvote and vote to close.

However, by contrast, there are some users who don't stumble across these questions very much but want to help improve the overall quality of SO. A good question requires domain knowledge to answer; a bad question is spotted even by someone unfamiliar with the subject.

The review queue (especially the close/delete/reopen queues) are meant to isolate that critiquing function and channel it into a productive space. Review queues also allow one to make very clear what one's opinion about a question is: a question is worth keeping open, a question should be closed, a question is worth reopening, a question is worth keeping closed, etc. This level of nuance in opinion is ***not*** available as part of the everyday usage of the site; I could +1 something but still VTC it, for example.

Why isn't the front page of the site more amenable to nuanced opinions? Well, frankly, that's just too much information for the average user. But a power user, someone who's been around for a minute, can tell that some questions aren't what they seem at first blush. That's why we have /review -- it's an *earned* privilege to participate in that space, and it asks reviewers to be more nuanced (and thoughtful) in their choices. The main pages don't allow for that kind of evaluation in the same way.

So, no, simply voting to close on main cannot constitute a `/review` task. It's not a 1:1 mapping -- the two are in no way synonymous.

Comment: This notion that the review queue is more "nuanced" that the regular page is new to me; I have no idea where that came from. I frequently click through to a question from the review page because the review interface is limiting. I don't see why a user who goes through homepage posts cleaning things up is somehow less than a user who goes through review posts cleaning things up

Comment: I can't say I'm particularly good at dealing with the bombardment of questions greatly varying in quality that is the review queue. I often skip like 3/4 of them because I feel they require domain knowledge I don't have or that they're simply what I consider borderline cases (and this is after wasting some time per question). But I still like to help when I have time, so in comes [a custom order](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/106699/get-unclosed-questions-with-closed-votes) that gives questions that have 4 close votes, so mostly less borderline. So no badge for me.

Comment: @Dukeling: heh... /review/close already prioritizes questions with more close votes, so you're kinda just duplicating functionality there. And it's not like 4 people can't still be *wrong*... There's nothing wrong with just skipping questions you don't feel qualified to evaluate, but might I suggest you use the filter to limit your reviews to tags you feel you have a good amount of familiarity with?

Comment: That's an angry -1 from me. Voting to close outside the review queue _is_ a review task (in the sense that you are reviewing content), the only difference with the "normal" review tasks is that it's thankless. Even if this was a ploy to get the badges, so what? It's about time we give a badge to close voters, we give badges for _everything_ these days. Visit an election page, get a badge. Visit the about page, get a badge. Close a question, and all you can hope to get is someone raging at you in comments or Meta.

Comment: @Shog9 I should note that I don't just close all questions that have 4 close votes. I give them all a fair review (and still skip where appropriate). They just have a habit of being worse quality than those I typically encounter in the review queue. Spending +-90% of my review time on borderline questions (in the review queue) is frustrating (and I can't identify borderline ahead of time), this time is much less with my new-found custom ordering. I tried specifying tags, but that only made it worse, since questions in my domain knowledge are typically more borderline.

Comment: @Dukeling: Note that you can filter the queues by tags if domain knowledge is a problem.

Comment: I disagree with that. Monitoring the questions on the main site and cv'ing/flagging them from there is as much a review task as using the review queue. It's just a different queue. I know that this is the primary mode of doing quality control of the php cv-ring. They are much more efficient keeping the crap from the php tag away than they would when using the actual review queue.

Comment: ...and since you've already put me in rage mode, why don't mod actions count towards the review badges? :<

Comment: @Dukeling: don't forget, in /review you have the ability to respond with "leave open" as well if a question isn't all that bad - which contributes toward marking a question as reviewed and thus eligible for vote-aging. This can take significantly more "reviewers" on the normal question page, since there it's based on *views*...

Comment: @Shog9 I know about "leave open". Note that borderline questions are not viable for "leave open". I think this functionality on the close window of the normal questions page would be cool, but I suppose there are reasons for not including this. This would also make it more review-task-y.

Comment: I don't get a badge for reading and responding to these comments either, @Yannis. The badges are there to encourage stepping outside of your comfort zone a bit, focusing on areas that have traditionally been overlooked. The idea of a badge for *closing* is a bit different (but not new - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25053/badge-for-closing-question).

Comment: If I'm not horribly mistaken you are not volunteering your time @Shog9.

Comment: @Shog9: Leave open is useful to get the reveiw badge w/o burning all close-votes ;)

Comment: Ploy to get badges? Not really ... or maybe. Basically I'd just like to get badges for things I do that other people get badges for doing (which I don't get simply because I do it in a *slightly* different way).

Comment: If you're tired of moderating, @Yannis - just let me know. If you're volunteering for something that makes you unhappy you should stop.

Comment: @Dukeling: borderline questions are certainly candidates for *editing*...

Comment: When I do get tired of moderating @Shog9, it would be nice to have a couple of badges as a memento of the work I've done... just saying...

Comment: @Shog9 Editing usually does not come into play. e.g. for duplicates, I can see the similarity between the questions, but don't quite know if they're close enough to be considered duplicates (or if the answers from one answers the other one). Similar for basically every other close reason.

Comment: @Yannis: the simplest solution there would be to move the flag queues over to the review system. This is something we've discussed a bit internally, but I don't think anyone's proposed it publicly yet - if you're interested, go ahead and toss it up.

Comment: @Dukeling: that's *definitely* an area where the filters are a huge win... You can either limit your duplicate reviews to tags where you have some depth of knowledge, or exclude duplicates entirely.

Comment: Aarthi I've read your answer twice and it still doesn't make any sense to me. I purposefully avoid /review, for a variety of reasons that aren't important, the point is I just don't use it. Are you seriously saying that I don't evaluate content on the sites I'm active on as vigorously and as carefully I would if I used /review? Am I not as productive a reviewer as any? Also participating in /review is not an earned privilege, as you can't do much if you first haven't earned the _actual_ privilege (fact that you can't use a queue if you haven't first earned the related privilege is telling).

Comment: @Shog9 I did exactly that (excl. duplicate (+ too localized)), but (1) it's "show these close reasons", not "exclude the others" (so a questions with e.g. 1 not constructive + 1 duplicate still shows up reasonably often). (2) (a) Not a real question is often difficult to judge lacking domain knowledge, (b) not constructive is often difficult to judge, (c) too localized I mostly have no idea about and (d) after reading the FAQ probably 100 times, I'm still sometimes unsure as to what's off topic (and this is probably the more boring one to review). Maybe I'm just not destined for review.

Comment: @Dukeling: there's no harm in avoiding /review/close until you feel comfortable making these decisions.

Comment: @Shog9 I suppose, not that I think it'd get better (just another part of being me). And I don't think [I can really say too much](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167109/close-votes-policy-review) about the seemingly ever-increasing close vote queue without doing my part to reduce it.