# Allow unaccepting an answer to a bounty question

Tags: feature-request, bounties, accepted-answer

Currently as it stands, once you open a bounty for a question, and once you've accepted an answer for that, you can never ever unaccept it anymore. And if a better answer appears or if you realize that you've make a mistake in accepting a wrong answer, you are out of luck (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560326/multiple-database-transaction)).

To me this is as unreasonable as [auto-accept answer after bounty period expires](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/please-do-not-auto-select-answers-on-bounty-questions). But I don't know what others think. I'm putting this up as a feature request.

Answer (score 5):

Do accepted answers have an expiration timer like votes do? If this were a feature, I think it would still have to be subject to the expiration timer.

As a practical matter, I think bounty answers should be chosen carefully.  If possible, the answer should be tested to see if the solution works before the answer is accepted.  Given SO's bias towards quick answers, the vote on a carefully-chosen answer shouldn't need to be changed, even if a better answer arrives later.

I wouldn't be opposed to a confirmation dialog:

```
This action cannot be changed later.  
Are you sure you want to award the bounty to this answer?
```

Comment: I like the warning idea. +1