# Bounty system shouldn't ask me if I'm sure before telling me I can't do it

Tags: feature-request, bounties, user-interface, bounty-dialog

This is not a big deal, just a minor UI complaint that I have about the process of awarding a bounty.

Currently, whenever a user tries to award a bounty, the very first thing that happens is a notification that pops up saying "Are you sure you want to award your bounty to this answer? THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE!" As far as I can tell, this kind of confirmation dialog was first suggested in the answer here: ([Allow unaccepting an answer to a bounty question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27005/306255)) and it makes sense to show it sometimes, since we currently don't allow unaccepting an answer.

However, it's unnecessary in situations where the system already doesn't allow the bounty to be awarded, such as before the 24 hour wait period is up or when trying to award it to deleted answers. (Actually, another odd thing is that I can try to award a bounty on a deleted answer, even though I can't try on my own. I guess it was thought to be too obvious to require comment that you can't give a bounty to yourself, but not obvious enough that you can't award it to deleted answers?)

So, in situations like these, there should be no confirmation dialogue, since it is not possible to complete the action in the first place. The confirmation dialogue should be a step that occurs AFTER the system checks to make sure that the user is mechanically capable of awarding the bounty.

Comment: "since we currently don't allow unaccepting an answer." - Well the author can unaccept an answer the bounty awarder can't take the bounty make.  You should be specific.

Comment: IMO the bounty award  button should be disabled if the user can't award the bounty yet, with tooltip explaining why. This will be consistent with other features, e.g. edit - users below 2k reputation will see a disabled "edit" link with a tooltip when they can't suggest edit on a  post. (other edit pending, edit ban etc)

Comment: lol, turns out I posted same comment on almost same question, almost year ago.